# Implementing logical shifts

Tags: bit-manipulation, shift

I need to implement a bitwise shift (logical, not arithmetic) on OpenInsight 8.

In the system mostly everything is a string but there are 4 functions that treat numbers as 32-bit integers. The bitwise functions available are AND, OR, NOT and XOR. Any arithmetic operators treat the number as signed.

I'm currently having a problem with implementing left and right shifts which I need to implement SHA-1.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm which can help me accomplish this? Pseudocode is good enough, I just need a general idea.

Comment: Do you really need to implement SHA1 yourself? No libraries available?

Comment: Nope... no libraries. I looked around to try and find one

Comment: Can you some code you have tried?

Comment: why don't you use hexadecimal in the code snippet above? Isn't 0x80000000 easier to understand than 2,147,483,648?

Comment: because that is a code snippet... and the language does not support hex constants

Answer (score 1):

You can implement shifting with integer multiplication and division:

Shift left = *2

Shift right = /2

Perhaps you need to mask the number first to make the most siginificant bit zero to prevent integer overflow.

Comment: I tried that already but something is just not working correctly. That's why i asked for pseudocode so i can see if i did something wrong

Comment: This won't work. Dividing a negative number by 2 rounds towards zero, whereas shifting a negative number right by 1 rounds towards negative infinity (and, for logical shifts, loses the sign bit).

Answer (score 0):

logical shift down by one bit using signed arithmetic and bitwise ops

```
if v < 0 then
   v = v & 0x7fffffff   // clear the top bit
   v = v / 2            // shift the rest down
   v = v + 0x40000000   // set the penultimate bit
else
   v = v / 2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no logical right shift you can easily achieve that by right shifting arithmetically n bits then clear the top n bits

For example: shift right 2 bits:

```c
x >= 2;
x &= 0x3fffffff;
```

Shift right n bits

```c
x >= n;
x &= ~(0xffffffff << (32 - n));
// or
x >= n;
x &= (1 << (32 - n)) - 1;
```

For left shifting there's no logical/mathematical differentiation because they are all the same, just shift 0s in.